# Swift chained closure?

Tags: swift, closures, chain

I have a `TaskExecutor` and a few `Task`s:

```
class TaskExecutor {
    func execute(_ task: Task, completion: ()->()) {
        // do something async here
        completion()
    }
}

class Task {
    // code for task
}
```

Now I need to execute tasks one after another - that is, the second task starts only when first task finishes, I know I can have a mutable array for the tasks, and keep taking the first (ie. next) from the array and execute it inside `TaskExecutor`'s completion closure, but is there any smart way of doing this?

I also thought about something like a `Chainable` protocol:

```
protocol Chainable<T> {
    var next: T?
}
```

And make `Task` conforming to it, then link all the tasks like a linked list, execute `next` after one's finished, but again, I feel there should be something easier and more straightforward.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by easier and more straightforward? Are the tasks known at compile time or are they dynamically created at runtime?

Comment: @Sweeper they are known at compile time, but this shouldn't matter; What I meant is that I wonder if there's better ways of doing this.

Comment: I think what need is to use promsies https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/under-the-hood-of-futures-and-promises-in-swift Or implement your own promise-like pattern.